# validate existence of a matching entry in database using rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, search, textfield

I need some help with the following problem. I would like to implement a text field into my view with a button that checks for an matching string in a database field.

More specifically, I have an accounts table with an email field. I would like to compare the user input in the textfield across all accounts and return `true` if there is a matching email, and `false` if the email does not match.

Is there a quick way to do this? I'm very new to rails, and thus far, all I have is the following code for the view:

```
  = text_field_tag :search
  = submit_tag "Check Email", :class => "submit"
```

Im not exactly sure what to put in the model or the controller, but I have written the following code and placed it in accounts.rb model:

```
  def email_exists?(search)
    return true if account.where(:email => "%#{search}%").exists?
  end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use Account.find_by_email rather than doing it all manually, and return the results of the empty? method.

That said, if this is part of a validation process, there are a number of ways to go about it--any Rails tutorial will have enough info to get you started, and you may be able to get away with its defaults rather than writing your own code (think validates_uniqueness_of, with some caveats).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to comunicate to your model is through controller actions.

The only way to access the controller actions is via http requests on your resources.

So:

1. Provide an action on your controller to check for the emails
2. Provide a method on your model to validate the emails (This you have already done)
3. Provide a route to access the action on the controller
4. Connect the submit field with the route to your controller action.

Note that if you ask the controller something, you will need to render the html response to this.

Im guessing you just want to notify the user if the email is available. To do this you will need to make an AJAX request. The same steps apply.